# What is the importance of God informing that Jesus Christ is the only begotten?

Tags: life-of-jesus

Exactly what God wants to teach us, in describing that Jesus is the only begotten son (only begotten - monogenes), because we see a parallel in generating Eve from Adam's ribs.

Comment: If you search (in the search box above) under the words 'only begotten' you will find a large number of questions and answers on the subject. I suggest you look through those as it is a big subject and there is division about what the word monogenes actually means, about which you will have to make up your own mind. Personally, I see no parallel (of the kind you appear to suggest) between the creative act of God making humanity and the divine begetting (an eternal begetting) which is the relationship of Father and Son, within Deity

Comment: If you have not already done so, please take our Tour to learn how to ask good, well-researched questions and to either direct your question to a specific Christian denomination or to ask for an overview: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour